# How to find time at any point on the path of a projectile motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, time, projectile

I know how to find the time of flight and all but what if I chose a random point on the path of the projectile (no air resistance) and ask the time at which the particle is present there, then how can we calculate that?

Comment: kinematic equations

Answer (score 1):

Using $x=u\cos(\theta)t$, we can find the time.

If any of the variable in the above equation is unknown, we can solve for that variable first using the equations of motion along $y$ axis.